# Two versions of same asp.net app using same server as stateserver - bad?

Tags: load-balancing, stateserver

We have 2 production web servers for our web app, load balanced to handle lots of traffic.

We also have a similar setup for testing.

```
Test pool:    [TEST 1]---[TEST 2] 

Prod pool:    [PROD 1]---[PROD 2]
```

When comparing the Web.Config of the app versions (test vs live) I discovered something surprising: both pools have the same value for stateConnectionString. If I understand right, this means they are using the same state server:

```
<sessionState 
mode="StateServer" 
stateConnectionString="tcpip=123.123.123.123:42424"
cookieless="false" 
timeout="30"/>
```

**Is this a problem?** (How does the state server not confuse the two pools)?

I was having odd only-sometimes slowdown/errors on the test server, that's why I was looking at this in the first place, but the prod pool runs fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this really means is that server `123.123.123.123` is the single source of all shared state for all servers on the web farm.

It's no different conceptually than storing the state in a centralized database, except in this case it's all stored on that one server in memory, and not a database.

I don't see anything *wrong* with it, per se..